# The variables max_connections,interactive_timeout,connect_timeout,etc in mysql donot satisfy my issue in angular2+ and nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I am using Observables in angular2+ that hits the nodejs which is the server that fetches data from the mysql database.Observables are used to get real-time data, so angular hits the mysql database within the mentioned time interval.

code -

```
   // Observables

    Observable.interval(10000).subscribe(x => {

    this.viewEntireData();

      });
```

So i set the sql variables here as -

```
  max_connections;
  interactive_timeout;
  wait_timeout;
  connect_timeout;


mysql> show variables like 'max_connections';
 +-----------------+--------+
 | Variable_name   | Value  |
  +-----------------+--------+
 | max_connections | 100000 |
 +-----------------+--------+



  mysql>show variables like 'wait_timeout';
   +---------------+-------+
   | Variable_name | Value |
   +---------------+-------+
   | wait_timeout  | 8800  |
   +---------------+-------+



  mysql> show variables like 'interactive_timeout';
  +---------------------+-------+
  | Variable_name       | Value |
  +---------------------+-------+
  | interactive_timeout | 8800  |
  +---------------------+-------+



    +-----------------+-------+
    | Variable_name   | Value |
    +-----------------+-------+
    | connect_timeout | 100   |
    +-----------------+-------+
```

With these values of the variables, my server gets closed . I get error -

```
  Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
```

Now , i want my connections to never close or end at all. Is it possible. Please help.

**UPDATED**

@Micheal - sqlbot

My variables are-

```
 mysql> SELECT @@log_warnings;
 +----------------+
 | @@log_warnings |
 +----------------+
 |              2 |
 +----------------+


 mysql> select @@version;
 +-------------------------+
 | @@version               |
 +-------------------------+
 | 5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
 +-------------------------+


 mysql> select @@log_error_verbosity;
 +-----------------------+
 | @@log_error_verbosity |
 +-----------------------+
 |                     3 |
 +-----------------------+
```

But still i am getting error -

"Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections"

Please help. According to your post, everything is fine. Still error.

Comment: Ensure that the global variable `@@log_warnings` on the server is set to a value not smaller than 2, and then see if you can correlate these events to anything in the MySQL error log. (`SELECT @@log_error;` to find the path to the error log on the server).  A connection that is being used every few seconds would not be closed by the server, with the settings you are showing, here.

Comment: hi michael....Please check my question updated section